# Allow Backorder for Admins only Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, backorder

Does anyone know how we can setup to allow backorders to happen only for orders placed in the backend admin?

So customers on the frontend store would not be able to place an order for an out of stock item.

Our sales reps need to be able to place orders for products that are out of stock, but not our frontend customers.

Is there an extension that would do this or any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please let us know,  What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Admin don’t care stock. Did try ever?

Comment: @pawan When I try to add a product that is out of stock to a new order in the admin.  I received 2 messages:  
  
1. We don't have as many "Product Name" as you requested.  
2. This product is out of stock.  
  
Store configuration is set to: No Backorders.  My understanding of this setting is that it applies to frontend customers. But it seems it is applying to backend as well.   
  
If I set the Backorder setting to: Allow below Zero.  I get the message:  
This product is out of stock.  
when trying to add the product to a new order in the backend.

Comment: @pawan 
Although it will allow me to add the product to an order with out of stock.  The stock number is not showing as negative.  Which is a problem because we dont know what has backorders then.

Answer (score 3):

My solution: change function get Config backorders

1- Create di.xml file in your module
Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration">
    <plugin name="custom_get_backorders" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomBackorders" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

2- Create CustomBackorders.php file

Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomBackorders.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;

class CustomBackorders
{

    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected $_backendSession;

    public function __construct(
        BackendSession $backendSession
    )
    {
        $this->_backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    public function afterGetBackorders(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Configuration $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->_backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $result = (int)1;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Solution, Thanks

Comment: This backendSession is initated on frontend too ? There can be some PHP session issues there ?

Comment: with class Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession; 
it only get end check user in backend, not on frontend

Comment: Casting 1 to int is redundant. Would you mind changing 1 to a constant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))? Moreover, you can return the result directly from if clause body. The di.xml config can be placed in etc/adminhtml scope which will remove this plugin from other scopes. Also protected field could be a private because plugins must not be extended (and you should avoid inheritance for cleaner code)