# Magento2.4.5: How to Allow Backorder for Admins only Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

I want only admin side to allow back orders when quantity is below zero.
I also appplied this solution but this didn't work.

[Allow Backorder for Admins only Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275096/allow-backorder-for-admins-only-magento-2)

Any Idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow Backorder for Admins only Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275096/allow-backorder-for-admins-only-magento-2)

Comment: i tried, but that class in that solution dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/code/Pyaray/RestrictCustomerOrder/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item">
        <plugin name="custom_get_backorders" type="Pyaray\RestrictCustomerBackOrders\Plugin\CustomBackorders" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> \Pyaray\RestrictCustomerOrder\Plugin\CustomBackorders.php

```
<?php

namespace Pyaray\RestrictCustomerOrder\Plugin;

use Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session as BackendSession;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item;

class CustomBackorders
{
    /**
     * @var BackendSession
     */
    protected BackendSession $backendSession;

    /**
     * @param BackendSession $backendSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        BackendSession $backendSession
    )
    {
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param Item $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return int
     */
    public function afterGetBackorders(Item $subject, $result): int
    {
        if ($this->backendSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            $result = 3;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for us as regardless of backorder configuration once a products is set top "Out of Stock" M2.4 will not allow the product to be backordered.